# Find $ \int \frac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^3} $

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to find the anti-derivative

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^3 }$$

**My attempt:**

By substitution:  $ x = a \tan(\theta)  \Rightarrow dx = a \sec^2(\theta) d\theta$

Then the integral becomes

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{ a \sec^2(\theta) d\theta }{a^6 \sec^6(\theta) } $$

And this reduces to

$$\dfrac{1}{a^5}  \displaystyle \int  \cos^4(\theta)  d\theta $$

Now, $\cos^4(\theta) = ( \cos^2(\theta) )^2 = \dfrac{1}{4} (1 + \cos(2 \theta) )^2 = \dfrac{1}{4} ( 1 + 2 \cos(2 \theta) + \cos^2(2 \theta) ) $

So this reduces to

$$ \cos^4(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{2} \cos(2 \theta) + \dfrac{1}{8} (1 + \cos(4 \theta) ) $$

and these are integrable easily, but I want to relate their integrals to the original variable $x$.

So, now I have the anti-derivative as

$$ \dfrac{3}{8} \theta + \dfrac{1}{4} \sin(2 \theta) + \dfrac{1}{32} \sin(4 \theta) $$

Since $ x = a \tan(\theta) $, then $ \cos(\theta) = \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}$, and $\sin(\theta) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} $

Hence

$$\sin(2 \theta) = \dfrac{ 2 a x }{x^2 + a^2} $$

$$\cos(2 \theta) = \dfrac{a^2 - x^2}{x^2 + a^2} $$

And finally,

$$\sin(4 \theta) = \dfrac{4 a x (a^2 - x^2) }{ (x^2 + a^2)^2} $$

Hence, my integral becomes

$$ \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^3} = \dfrac{1}{a^5}\left( \dfrac{3}{8} \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right) + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{a x }{x^2 + a^2} + \dfrac{1}{8} \dfrac{ a x (a^2 - x^2) }{ (x^2 + a^2)^2 } \right) + C $$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant of integration.

**And my question is:** Are my approach and derivation correct?

Comment: Yes.  I plugged your answer into Maple, differentiated, and got $1/(x^2+a^2)^3$.

Comment: Thank you.  That's re-assuring.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631747/integration-by-parts-int-fracdxx2-a2n/1631973#1631973

Comment: Here's yet another way: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689932/1242

Comment: Thanks @HansLundmark I found your link very useful.

Comment: Thanks @boojum for the related answer.

Comment: **TeX:** Abuse of `\displaystyle` and `\dfrac`, especially [in the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730). Why not just `$${STUFF}$$`, instead of `$\displaystyle{STUFF}$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, integrate by parts to avoid the trig substitution
\begin{align}
I_3=&\int \frac{1}{(x^2 + a^2)^3 }dx
=\int \frac{1}{4a^2x^3}d\left(\frac{x^4}{ (x^2 + a^2)^2}\right)
= \frac{x}{4a^2 (x^2 + a^2)^2}+\frac3{4a^2}I_2\\
I_2=&\int \frac{1}{(x^2 + a^2)^2}dx
=\int \frac{1}{2a^2x}d\left(\frac{x^2}{ x^2 + a^2}\right)
=\frac{x}{2a^2 (x^2 + a^2)}+\frac1{2a^2}I_1\\
I_1=&\int \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}dx= \frac1a \tan^{-1}\frac xa
\end{align}
which leads to
$$I_3
= \frac{x}{4a^2 (x^2 + a^2)^2}+ \frac{3x}{8a^4 (x^2 + a^2)}+
\frac{3}{8a^5}\tan^{-1}\frac xa +C
$$

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore, I am going to find the integral in general

$$
I_{n}=\int \frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n}} d x
$$

by a reduction formula by noting that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d x}\left[\frac{x}{\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n}}\right] &=\frac{a^{2}+(1-2 n) x^{2}}{\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n+1}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n}}-2 n \cdot \frac{x^{2}+a^{2}-a^{2}}{\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n+1}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n}}-2 n\left[\frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n}}-\frac{a^{2}}{\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n+1}}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating both sides w.r.t. $x$ yields $$
\boxed{I_{n+1}=\frac{x}{2 n a^{2}\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{n}}+\frac{2 n-1}{2 n a^{2}} I_{n}}
$$
In particular, when $n=2$,

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{3} &=\frac{x}{4 a^{2}\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{3}{4 a^{2}} I_{2} \\
&=\frac{x}{4 a^{2}\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{3}{4 a^{2}}\left[\frac{x}{2 a^{2}\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2 a^{2}} I_{1}\right] \\
&=\boxed{\frac{x}{4 a^{2}\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{3 x}{8 a^{4}\left(x^{2}+a^{2}\right)}+\frac{3}{8 a^{5}} \tan ^{-1} \frac{x}{a}+C}
\end{aligned}
$$